# Schedule powershell script with admin priviliges

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, powershell, task-scheduler

I want to schedule a powershell script to run on my windows 7 system everyday with admin priviliges.
How do I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `schtasks`, from an elevated CMD prompt.

eg.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My Task Name" /ru Administrator /sc daily /sd 28/05/2011 /st 14:00 /tr "powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -file %MyPATH%\MyTaskScript.ps1"
```

This would run the script at 14:00 every day.